# Differential rents problem solving for transport problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, operations-research

Sorry if question was asked, but I was unable to find the exact duplicate. Let's assume that we have transport problem.

1. Will optimal plan for transport problem be the same regardless the method I use? I mean should optimal plan be the same when I use potentials method and differential rents method?
2. Do you know any good visualizes or examples of solving transport problem via differential rents method?

Thank you.